# jQuery, only trigger event, if no other event was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way, to find out, if a jquery event was already caught by another event-listener?

The following example: I have the following event bindings:

```
$("body").on("click", ".linkarea", function (e) {
    document.location.href = $(this).find("a")a.attr("href");
});
$("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    console.log("DELETE");
});
```

This is how my HTML look like:

```
<div class="linkarea">
    <h1><a href="/test.html">LINKED</a></h1>
    <p>Blabla</p>   
    <a class="btn delete">DELETE</a>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is, that if an user clicks on any part of the div (except the .delete button), he should be redirected to /test.html. If he clicks on .delete button, only(!) the other event code should be executed.

I know, that I could add "e.stopPropagation()" to the delete-event, but maybe I use the .delete class on another place, and there it could be necessary, that it bubbles. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".linkarea", function (e) {
    if(!e.wasAlreadyExecuted)
        document.location.href = $(this).find("a")a.attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Why do you have an event listener on something that by default already does what you are doing with the listener: go to another page?

Comment: Because a click on a div by default does nothing. I know, I could change the div to an a-element, but thats not a good idea from SEO perspective.

Comment: But you already have an `a` tag in there, which does what you want.

Comment: Yes, but it should also goto /test.html, if the user clicks on the <p>Blabla</p> or on the other areas of the div (for example the background). There could be an image inside this div as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter it out regarding `event.target`:

```
$("body").on("click", ".linkarea", function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('.delete').length) return;
    document.location.href = $(this).find("a")a.attr("href");
});
```

***EDIT:***

> I know, that I could add "e.stopPropagation()" to the delete-event,
>   but maybe I use the .delete class on another place, and there it could
>   be necessary, that it bubbles.

<strike>Or stop event propagation from `.delete` click handler:</strike>

```
$("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    console.log("DELETE");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Ok, thats the right direction! But since I want to have an independent and reusable code, I can't test against ".delete", because there can be other events as well like add, move, publish, whatever..

Comment: @leftjustified So just use a common class for all elements you want to exclude, e.g: `.btn`. That's said, you could filter regarding `$._data` of event target  to check if any other click event is bound but that's not the way it should be done

Comment: Ok, thats a clean solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check the [event current target](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp):

```
$("body").on("click", ".linkarea", function (event) {
   if(event.currentTarget.className.match(/delete/)){
         //your stuff
   }else{
          //your other stuff
   }
});
```

Just be aware that it won't work on IE8-